# Django: Fields in inlineformset to display only logged in users Authors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

How to create new titles for authors using inlineformset factory by selecting authors created by logged in users only.

**Models.Py**

```
    Model1
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    Model2
    Author_for_title=models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now i want to have a form where users can select the Author and type title in input field to update.

So far everything is fine. But only thing i am not able to solve is that:

> How to use queryset so that Author select field display authors
>   created by logged in Users only?

```
formset=inlineformset_factory(Model1,Model2,,can_delete=True,fields=('__all__',),extra=3)
```

I found no answer anywhere, please help with an example.

Comment: Hi, To be clear. Are you looking to have a form where in you can add multiple Model2 objects under Model1? You seem to be having correct code. What problem are you facing. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Amar got the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, thanks to documentation.

in views.py

```
new_formset = inlineformset_factory(Model1,Model2,can_delete=False,exclude=('user',),extra=3)
for forms in new_formset:
        forms.fields['Author_for_title'].queryset = Model1.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```